# about Bochner–Khinchin’s Theorem for characteristic function

Tags: probability

Bochner–Khinchin’s Theorem gives A necessary and sufficient condition for a continuous function ϕ(t) with ϕ(0) = 1 to be characteristic, and its proof is usually skipped in most textbooks. Is there similar conditions for a given function to be a probability generating function  (or a moment generating function). 
if these conditions exist, can someone gives me a proof of how to find them? Thanks